# User search from multiple values in php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to achieve a simple search tool to search from the database by using user inputs.

The form has 3 fields to enter inputs:
[image: the form appearance]

However when I search one by one, only the top one is functioning properly and others just gives the whole set of database records.
This is HTML form.

```
<table> <tbody>
<tr>
    <p style="padding:5px;">Судалгааны чиглэл:</p>
    <input type="text" name="get_sudalgaa" id="search" 
    class="searchTerm" style="width: 81%; margin-bottom: 15px;" 
    placeholder="Хайх эрдэмтний овог нэрийг оруулна уу?" >
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button type="submit" name="search_by_id" value="" class="btn btn- 
    success searchButton" style="width: 15%; height: 40px; margin- 
    bottom: 8px;">Хайх</button>
 </tr>     </br>

<tr>    <p>Овог:</p>    <input type="text" name="get_ovog" id="search" class="searchTerm">    <p style="padding:5px;">Нэр:</p>    <input type="text" nrame="get_ner" id="search" class="searchTerm"> </tr> </tbody> </table>

<?php $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","sci");  $connection -> set_charset("utf8"); if(isset($_POST['search_by_id'])){ $ovog=$_POST['get_ovog'];   $ner=$_POST['get_ner'];   $sudalgaa=$_POST['get_sudalgaa'];   $query="SELECT * FROM sci_st WHERE Id='get_id' OR Ovog='$ovog' OR Ner='$ner' OR Sudalgaa='{%$sudalgaa%}'";
                 
               $query_run=mysqli_query($connection,$query); ?>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the issue. We can't see where these variables are coming from, or what data is in your database, or what precise output you're getting. We only have one out-of-context line of code, and an un-specific description of the problem without a concrete example. See also [ask]. You can [edit] your post when you're ready, and then we can provide far more meaningful help.

Comment: Also we don't know your precise requirements. Your first version of the query looks like it would probably make more sense, but then we don't have a specification of how the search is supposed to work.

Comment: `When using else if only the top condition works`...do you know what `else if` means? If the code enters the `if`, then it will never go into any of the `else` or `else if` conditions in the same block. That's how it works. If you don't want that, don't write it like that.

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). Even [if you are escaping inputs, it's not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API instead of concatenating user-provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: try like this: `$query = "SELECT * FROM sci_st WHERE ";

if($_POST['get_lastname '] != ' '){
  $query .= "Lastname  = $lastname ";
}
if($_POST['get_firstname'] != ' '){
  $query .= "OR WHERE Firstname = $firstname ";
}
if($_POST['get_research'] != ' '){
  $query .= "OR Research LIKE '%" .$research. "%'";
}`

Answer (score -1):

In such type of **Search Forms** if a user provides multiple fields data (e.g Firstname, Lastname, research) then those records from database should be retrieved where all these keywords are matched. It means you should use **"AND"** operator in your SQL query. It is a best approach.
If you use "OR" operator then the retrieved records will have no useful information as each data field (e.g Firstname, lastname, research) will have its own records which have no connection with each other.

**THE BEST APPROACH**

The best approach is to use "AND" operator as below as mentioned in @anant comment but with AND operator:

```
if(!empty($lastname) OR !empty($firstname) OR !empty($_POST['get_research'])) {

    if(!empty($lastname))
            $condition = "Lastname  = '$lastname' "; 
    else
            $condition = "1=1 "; 

    if(!empty($firstname))
            $condition .= "AND WHERE Firstname = '$firstname' ";

    if(!empty($_POST['get_research']))
            $condition .= "AND Research LIKE '%" .$research. "%'";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM sci_st WHERE ".$condition; 
  }
```